# Last observation carried forward (locf) on xts in r? (not like na.approx?)

Tags: r, xts

I would like to have "Last Observation Carried Forward (LOCF)" from one xts time series to another xts series containing the time stamps that I would like to use. I have tried with `na.locf` but `xout` does not seem to work as I know from `na.approx`.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

**Here is an example:**

***I have*** two xts time series data sets. One with my data and another with time stamps that I would like to use.

```
xts_with_data <- as.xts(read.zoo(text='
2016-07-01 00:00:10,   1.0
2016-07-01 00:00:14,   2.0
2016-07-01 00:00:20,   3.0
2016-07-01 00:00:29,   4.0
2016-07-01 00:00:34,   5.0
2016-07-01 00:00:39,   6.0
', sep=',', index=1, tz='', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
names(xts_with_data) <- c('x')

xts_with_timestamps <- as.xts(read.zoo(text='
2016-07-01 00:00:15,   0.0
2016-07-01 00:00:20,   0.0
2016-07-01 00:00:30,   0.0
2016-07-01 00:00:35,   0.0
2016-07-01 00:00:38,   0.0
', sep=',', index=1, tz='', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

***What I would like, is this***:

```
                    [,1]
2016-07-01 00:00:15    2
2016-07-01 00:00:20    3
2016-07-01 00:00:30    4
2016-07-01 00:00:35    5
2016-07-01 00:00:38    5
```

(i.e. the time stamp from `xts_with_timestamps` and corresponding locf from `xts_with_data`).

I thought I could do it with `xout` like this (which works fine for `na.approx`):

```
na.locf(xts_with_data, xout = index(xts_with_timestamps))
```

but that just returns my original `xts_with_data`.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like the source of your troubles is a missing feature in `xts:::na.locf.xts`. It might be worth letting Joshua (the developer) know, if he doesn't already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `merge()` to join the two series before applying `na.locf()` can be one approach.

```
xts_all <- merge(xts_with_data, xts_with_timestamps)[,-2]
na.locf(xts_all)[index(xts_with_timestamps)]

#                     x
# 2016-07-01 00:00:15 2
# 2016-07-01 00:00:20 3
# 2016-07-01 00:00:30 4
# 2016-07-01 00:00:35 5
# 2016-07-01 00:00:38 5
```

It seems like the reason why `xout` works for `na.approx()` but not for `na.locf()` is that there is an `xts` method for the latter which doesn't seem to pass on extra arguments correctly. You can however force the use of the default method, and thus restore the support for `xout`

```
na.locf.default(xts_with_data, xout=index(xts_with_timestamps))
# or
na.locf(zoo(xts_with_data), xout=index(xts_with_timestamps))

#                     x
# 2016-07-01 00:00:15 2
# 2016-07-01 00:00:20 3
# 2016-07-01 00:00:30 4
# 2016-07-01 00:00:35 5
# 2016-07-01 00:00:38 5
```

Comment: Great with the clarification on xout! Thanks. Both work fine for me though latter seems easier reading.